# Clone drive to a smaller one

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, flash, clone

I have a hard disk with 3 partitions on it. (one Linux-swap and two Ext3)

The drive is a 2TB USB drive, and I would need to clone it onto a 16GB USB flash drive.

The first two partitions are small (about 2GB in total), the third is as big as the rest of the remaining drive, but is empty.

I’d need to copy over the two smaller partitions as they are to the USB flash drive, and the third one as big as it can get on the drive.

My thought was to connect the 2TB drive to the computer and use GParted to reduce the size of the huge partition to about 1GB.

Then make an image with Win32 Disk Imager and flash it to the thumb drive. Then as last step use GParted to increase the size of the third partition.

But before I procede, I’d need to be sure that this is the best way to do it and that I do not risk to lose the data.

Comment: It's a drive attached to a dd-wrt router running Linux. I do have a Windows cd and a GParted Live cd.

Answer (score 1):

Do it all in Linux. Start by resizing the third partition, as you mention. No need to take it down to 1GB, just make it small enough to fit on the flashdrive. Should be simple enough.

Then, you can copy the entire disk image from the external drive to the flashdrive using the `dd` command. You should definitely read the dd manual (`man dd`) before trying anything, but it's not *that* complex a program. Something like `dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=16M count=1000` or so should work (note the use of devices like `sdb` instead of, say, `sdb1`; we are copying entire block devices, not just partitions). Make sure that you'll get all the relevant bits (that is, that `bs` * `count` is big enough to encompass all the relevant data). Note that, without a decently large block size (`bs` parameter), `dd` can be pretty slow.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I do not have Linux.. only a GParted Live cd..

Comment: Any Live CD with `gparted` on it almost certainly has `dd` as well; it's a very standard utility on all Unix-like OSes for a long time now. You can easily download another Live CD if you want to, though. There's lots of them out there, and most will have `gparted` or possibly the KDE equivalent, `qtparted`.